# How do I hook up a lava lamp / ambient orb to my build?

Tags: build, visibility

I want to have a lava lamp / ambient orb / colorful light turn green when my build is good and red when it is bad.

Is there a product that does this?  What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Quite possibly irrelevant, but quite a few continuous integration systems (TeamCity, etc.) have accompanying Windows tray notification apps. Less fun, but handy none the less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you go](http://www.hostfrontier.com/index.php/200810317/agile-methodology/integrating-lava-lamps-to-cruisecontrol.html). Happy geeking :-)